# net gain/loss in python

Tags: python

I'm doing a project where I need to figure if my transactions will earn me a profit or hit me for a loss. It's based on buying and selling stocks with commission. I got the basic math concept all worked out. What I am struggling with is the last equation where I subtract the sale price from the purchase price. I need a statement (or two) that if the answer is positive, it will go to output saying I gained x amount of money. If the answer is negative, it will go to output saying I lost x amount of money.

What statements could I use where the Python program will know to send positive number to gain output and negative number to loss output?

Here's the code I wrote with your suggestion for if statement

```
number_of_shares = input("Enter number of shares: ")
purchase_price = input("Enter purchase price: ")
sale_price = input("Enter sale price: ")

price = number_of_shares * purchase_price
first_commission = price * .03
final_price = price - first_commission

sale = number_of_shares * sale_price
second_commission = sale * .03
last_price = sale - second_commission

net = final_price - last_price
if (net > 0):
print("After the transaction, you gained", net, "dollars.")
if (net < 0):
print("After the transaction, you lost", net, "dollars.")
```

I didn't realize I was putting the loss as a gain and vice versa so I swapped it around and changed the wording to make it more clear. I'm still stuck here's my updated code

```
number_of_shares = input("Enter number of shares: ")
purchase_price = input("Enter purchase price: ")
sale_price = input("Enter sale price: ")

price = number_of_shares * purchase_price
first_commission = price * .03
buy_price = price - first_commission

sale = number_of_shares * sale_price
second_commission = sale * .03
sell_price = sale - second_commission

net = sell_price - buy_price
if net > 0:
    print("After the transaction, you gained", net, "dollars.")
if net < 0:
    print("After the transaction, you lost", net, "dollars.")
```

After doing the code on paper, I saw my mistake (with the commission) and made changes. Now my issue is when the net is for a loss, the output gives me an negative number. How do i make it not negative? since I already have the statement- you lost x dollars. Hmm multiplying by negative 1? Here's what I did

```
number_of_shares = int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
purchase_price = float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
sale_price = float(input("Enter sale price: "))

buy = float(number_of_shares * purchase_price)
first_commission = float(buy * .03)

sale = float(number_of_shares * sale_price)
second_commission = float(sale * .03)

net = float(sale - buy - first_commission - second_commission)
if net > 0:
    print("After the transaction, you gained", net, "dollars.")
if net < 0:
    print("After the transaction, you lost", net * -1, "dollars.")
```

Comment: Hint: less than or greater than

Comment: Yeah I had thought of that but didn't know how to incorporate that until I saw the if statement suggestion from the other person. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code you have so far it's a bit hard to give you help, but I'll try anyways.

It sounds like you're looking for an `if` statement. The following will probably do what you want:

```
# Assuming total_money is the output of everything before
# positive number is gain, negative is loss
if total_money > 0:
    print 'You gained ${}'.format(total_money)
else:
    print 'You lost ${}'.format(total_money)
```

This is part of a concept called flow control. To learn more about it, you can look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: 0 isn't a "loss" per se.

Comment: Hmmm! Lemme try that!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following format:

```
net_change = sell_price - buy_price - commission
if (net_change >0):
    print('Money! Money in the bank!\nYou have made $'+str(net_change))
else if (net_change <0):
    print('Oh, sad deleterious day!\nYou have lost $'+str(net_change))
else:
    print('You did not accomplish anything. You have broken even.')
```

This is a flow control path for three outcomes, Positive, Negative, and Neutral.
You'll find that flow control such as this is key to creating robust programs, it prevents the program from going to a place that it shouldn't.

Comment: The assignment doesn't allow for neutral outcome. But I just noticed the part     str(net_charge). I'll try that

Comment: It does allow for neutral outcomes, the final `else` statement is called if there is no gain or loss, it's therefore an implicit `else if (net_change ==0):`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked

```
number_of_shares = int(input("Enter number of shares:"))
purchase_price = float(input("Enter purchase price:"))
sale_price = float(input("Enter sale price:"))

buy = float(number_of_shares * purchase_price)
first_commission = float(buy * .03)

sale = float(number_of_shares * sale_price)
second_commission = float(sale * .03)

net = float(sale - buy - first_commission - second_commission)
if net > 0:
    print("After the transaction, you gained", net, "dollars.")
if net < 0:
    print("After the transaction, you lost", net * -1, "dollars.")
```